# Would the shortening of a word constitute the use of an apostrophe?

Tags: apostrophe

The first example I see often is usually along the lines of "**Go get 'em!**".

In personal training muscles are often spoken of in a shortened manner, for example triceps are called tri's. Would this be valid use of an apostrophe?

Comment: I think `tris` would be confusing. However, if it's in written form why wouldn't you spell `triceps` out fully?

Comment: Triceps is probably not the best example, the majority of muscle names are long and tedious to write out in full when both parties know what's being referred to with the shortened reference. Let's take gluteus maximus for example...it's normally referred to as glute's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the triceps: It seems to be perfectly acceptable to use an apostrophe to denote plural in such cases. Personally, I would also argue it often helps eliminate confusion.

Consider:

> **bi**: a bisexual person
>
> plural: bis or **bi's**

(AHD)

Or:

> **a**: the first letter of the English alphabet
>
> plural: **a's** or as

(Webster's Unabridged)

In **go get 'em** the **'em** part is a contraction, so it uses an apostrophe to indicate omission. Contraction is defined by Webster's Unabridged like so:

> a shortening of a word, syllable, or word group by omission of one or
> more sounds or letters or by the reduction of two or more vowels or
> syllables to one — used especially of shortening in the interior of a
> word (as **e'er** for *ever*) and of shortening of enclitics (as *'ll* for
> *will* in **they'll**) and proclitics (as *'t* for *it* in **'t is**).

Comment: _Go get ’em_ isn't actually a contraction. It's the same number of syllables as the full form; only a single consonant is omitted. _E’er_ is not a contraction because the v is omitted, but because it's reduced from two syllables (/e.vər/) to one (/er/).

Comment: More relevant is actually _a’s_, even though no letters are left out: monosyllabic words ending in (phonetically long, graphemically simplex) vowels tend to be pluralised either with or without apostrophes, even when fully written out: one do, two do(’)s; one pi, two pi(’)s; one la, two la(’)s, etc.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It seems *'em* fits the definition of contraction, as defined in Webster's. Omission of **one or more sounds** is part of the definition.

Comment: I feel like this response best answers my question. Thanks @A.P.

Answer (score 2):

I think the apostrophe is usually used when a word is shortened by cutting out the front.

"Go get **'em**."

"I been working out my **'ceps** a lot."

"I gotta let my **'rents** know I'm coming home late."

When a word is shortened by cutting off the end, it is not usually accompanied by an apostrophe.

"Grab your **sneaks** before we go."

"What are the **stats** on that player?"

"My **abs** are still sore from the core workout yesterday."

Comment: Yes, *sneak/stat/ab* became words. For the first part, 'cause, I'm, they're, I'd,  could be good examples.